# Golang Cloud Function failed deployment missing dot in first path element

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, go-modules

I tried to deploy Golang Project with module = `mymodule`, but failed with below error

```
Deployment failure:
Build failed: {"error":{"buildpackId":"google.go.functions-framework","buildpackVersion":"0.9.0","errorType":13,"canonicalCode":13,"errorId":"131fbb9d"
,"errorMessage":"go mod: -require=mymodule@v0.0.0: invalid path: malformed module path \"mymodule\":
missing dot in first path element"},"stats":null}
```

If I rename the `mymodule` to have dot within it, e.g. `mymodule.test` , then it fails in my local as it tried to fetch it externally from `https://mymodule.test` which does not exist

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide reproducible steps so I could test it from my side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define in your `go.mod` file a local module, like this

```
require mymodule.test v0.0.0

replace mymodule.test v0.0.0=> ./path/to/mymodule
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I tried to use replace for some reason it tries to fetch from `GOROOT` folder instead of `project root` folder, hence returns another error `cmd\main.go:13:2: package //mymodule.test/graph/resolvers is not in GOROOT (c:\go\src\mymodule.test\graph\resolvers)`

Comment: Can you share your project structure?

Comment: After putting `replace mymodule.test => ./` in the last line of `go.mod`, and modify all other places to use `mymodule.test` , I was able to deploy in GCP, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Go module name will be interpreted as a URL from which the given project is available. You have to name your module by your project's URL. E.g. `github.com/iwan/yourproject`, assuming your project is under `github.com/iwan/yourproject`.

#### Reason

When you publish your go module and it is being built into gcloud, your module will be imported (see the error message: `go mod: -require=mymodule@v0.0.0`). The standard go module import process will verify the checksum of the available module by fetching the contents of `https://<your_module_name>@v.0.0.0`.

That is why you get a complain about the missing '.', because it tries to make sure you provided a valid URL. And that is why it fails when you named it `mymodule.test` because the URL, the go module indicates (i.e. `https://mymodule.test`) is unavailable.

Comment: Thank you @aliras. The explanation makes sense for external dependencies. But for the code in the local project i.e. the project module itself (that already available within google cloud source repository) -- probably it should not attempt to interpret the module name as URL